# Bash- ${line,,}: bad substitution

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have trouble with lowercasing the words from textfile. I am running on Bash 4.4(OS X) and it should be possible to do it by using two commas after variable but it throw me error:

> ${line,,}: bad substitution

Here is my simple code:

```
filename=textfile.txt
while read -r line
do
        word="${line,,}"
        echo "$word"
done < "$filename"
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: your code works in my linux environment which has bash 4.3.46, how did you confirm that you are using 4.4 ? try placing `echo $BASH_VERSION` in your code to check the version.

Comment: got same error in `3.1.7(1)-release` bash. However it worked for later versions.

Comment: There is the problem. When i run command `bash --version` it returns  `version 4.4.0(1)-release` but when i run command ($BASH_VERSION) in the code it returns  `3.2.57(1)` any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: may be using a `#!/bin/sh` in your script? as a fix you should change it to `#!/bin/bash` as the former is a minimal POSIX compliant shell which is expected to have lesser features only

Comment: i tried to run command `echo $BASH_VERSION` in terminal instead of VIM and it show 4.4.0, so I think that the vim works on wrong version of bash, but it's weird.

Comment: I am using #!/bin/sh but i forgot to post it there.

Comment: @prone666: change it to `#!/bin/bash` and it should work fine.

Comment: @prone666: are you sure the error is `bad subscription`, can you please check it , if its `bad substitution`?

Comment: I tried using `#!/bin/bash`  and it didn't work. And yes, it's bad substittion, my fault, i am sorry.

Comment: if you run "sh script.sh",  try this; "./script.sh"

Comment: i am running always ./script.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution for my answer, so it could be helpful for someone to post it there. When I've updated bash, it has only updated to `usr` directory  so when you run `#!usr/local/bin/bash` it would work correctly. For upgrading bash globally see this tutorial: http://clubmate.fi/upgrade-to-bash-4-in-mac-os-x/